# position: relative lost after translate3d

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a span in a div that scrolls, i.e the span stays centered and doesn't scroll while the rest of the text in the div scrolls. I've managed to do this using position: relative, but for some reason when I use translate3d the position: relative attribute is lost.

without translate3d 
http://jsbin.com/etowuh/4/edit

with translate 3d
http://jsbin.com/etowuh/6/edit

Is there any way to use translate3d while keeping the "stay centered" text centered?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/arusor/edit#javascript,html

Comment: translate3d needs to be applied to the #scroller (I mistakenly had it under #wrapper; fixed now), so using translate3d on #wrapper3d won't work.

Comment: I'm viewing it in chrome. without translate 3d http://jsbin.com/etowuh/4/edit <= right "stay centered" is fixed & scrolls, with the added wrapper3d & translate3d http://jsbin.com/arusor/edit#javascript,html <= right "stay centered" stays fixed & scrolls, with translate3d on #scroller  right "stay centered" moves with its parent http://jsbin.com/ekoqes/edit#javascript,html . Either your question wasn't clear or you was after a different result.

Comment: Thanks for the help Julien. I think my question wasn't very clear. Let me try again. I want the "stay centered" text to stay centered when I apply translate3d to the #scroller div, which will make the div appear to scroll. Applying translate3d to #wrapper or #wrapper3d will just shift the div, which is not what I'm after. Hope that clarifies things.